# OS copy/paste not working for emacs-mac

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, evil, emacs-mac-port

`GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0, Carbon Version 157 AppKit 1504.83) of 2019-01-27`

I just recently installed the emacs-mac port of GNU Emacs 26, and the OS copy/paste functionality does not seem to work. I am on using the GUI so my understanding is the functionality should work OOB (It does for non-port)

I am not able to copy text from my OS into emacs or vice/versa.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If copy/paste does not work with zero user-configuration, then you should file a bug report with the maintainer of that port.  If copy/paste works as expected with zero user-configuration, then you may need to bisect your user-configuration by commenting stuff out (save, restart, repeat process) until you find the culprit.

Comment: I have the Cocoa version (GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0, NS appkit-1348.17 Version 10.10.5 (Build 14F2511)) of 2019-04-12) and there it works out of the box. The key binding is defined in ns-win.el.gz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a verbatim paste of my homegrown configuration for getting system clipboard integration on macOS. I installed Emacs with `brew`, if that makes a difference.

```el
;; This works for copying, but not pasting for some reason
(setq select-enable-clipboard t)

;; Whatever... it's easy enough to implement that part ourselves
(setq interprogram-paste-function
      (lambda ()
        (shell-command-to-string "pbpaste")))
```

It does the trick for me. Let me know if it works for you, too.

Comment: This is functionally what I was looking for. I'll have to rebind some keys for my config but it works!

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: This is a great, but the second command is un-balanced (extra right paren)

Comment: @ZephaniahGrunschlag Fixed